# How can I make a 'button' create a movable DIV onMouseDown, and switch the 'MouseDown' to the new DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

So I haven't yet started writing any of this, so I'll do my best to put together some pseudocode for the sake of clarity - but the idea here is that a user would click and hold on a 'button' ( might not end up being an actual button ), that then spawns a movable DIV. Once the DIV has been created ( wherever the mouse is at the time, perhaps offset a little so the mouse is inside the div ), I'd like to switch my 'hold focus' to the new, movable DIV, so that it can be positioned on the screen; at which time I'll do some other operations on the DIV - but after this point the remainder is irrelevant to the question.

In true, incomplete pseudocode - this is roughly what I'm after; and I believe that my biggest question here is how to actually change my grab focus.

```
<script>
function NewDiv()
{
   NewDiv = CreateDiv(MouseX, MouseY);
   GrabDiv(NewDiv);
}

function CreateDiv(X, Y)
{
    // DOM for a new DIV... I've got this part covered...
    // JQuery for Movable - Covered
    NewDiv.style.left=(X - 3) + "px";
    NewDiv.style.top=(Y - 3) + "px";

    return NewDiv;
}

function GrabDiv(Div)
{
    // Here's the question...

    // Div.Focus? - While the mouse is still down, I might think this would work?
    // Div.onMouseDown? - Buuuuuut... Is that going to interact with the mouse properly?
}

</script>

<input type='button' onMouseDown='NewDiv();' value="Spawn a new Div" />
```

Now - again, the real question is what the 'proper' approach to the 'GrabDiv' function would be. Any feedback is much appreciated; and if I need to elaborate at all I'm glad to.

-- It looks like there may have been at least one other post on something like this; with a pretty convoluted answer. Perhaps this little bump will encourage a new answer. Hopes.

Comment: Just for the sake of making it a little bit easier.. if you actually include the jquery user interface (jqueryUI), there is a very comfort prototype that allows you to make a div draggable: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: Yeah I'm going to use JQuery-UI for the draggable element; I'm more curious how to switch the focus from a click TO that drag. But thank you sir; a valid recommendation.

Comment: @DigitalJedi805 basically you just want to create a draggable div wherever the user clicks ?

Comment: @DigitalJedi805: z-index and jQuery.focus? ;) You can actually add an event listener to the div that you're spawning, I would personally recommend you to implement a generic class that expects the ID of the div you want to spawn and some additional parameters that gives you the properties of the div itself, like Z-index priority and so on.. i'll try with a fiddle :P

Comment: Definitely some good suggestions @briosheje - if you are ( as you seem to be ) so inclined as to fiddle it; I'll be ecstatic. Thank you.

Comment: More or less @darkyen00 - but I want to immediately grab that div when it is created.

Comment: just a side question: what do you mean by "focusing" the draggable div?

Comment: Um... Basically just changing the object that is attached to the mouse down event... I think that 12hys' linked implementation may be the ticket...

Comment: I'm not still sure what you want to do with that mousedown or just whatever, but here is the rest you wanted to do: http://jsfiddle.net/briosheje/bfaupz7v/ this fiddle includes a very very very very basic object that will implement a draggable div and will apply the properties you pass into the third parameters as css properties. The div will be spawned on the mouse coords positions. Oviously, to create different divs, just implement something that allows you to decide the ID of the div you have to create.

Comment: Also, updated the fiddle to give you an idea of how to control, later, every single div you have to add: http://jsfiddle.net/briosheje/bfaupz7v/1/ since I'm not sure this is exactly what you're looking for I'm not going to be posting an answer, feel free to ask if you have any problem with the fiddle :)

Comment: Awesome man; I'm grubbing down on some lunch right now lol - but once I get through that I'll go scope the fiddle and let you know if this is what I'm after - but it sounds like it. You should re-post as an answer and I'll up it for sure; might even end up using this solution in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this working somewhere else?

I would look into using jQuery-UI's drag and drop.

Edit: I guess it does work. I would use this jsbin as a starting point: http://jsbin.com/deyovunaxe/2/edit

Comment: How is this a security risk? It's creating an element, switching focus and triggering a draggable event.

Comment: @12hys he can very well by using triggerEvent

Comment: Nvm, I misunderstood, I was thinking that you wanted to move the mouse pointer.

Comment: Um... I'm not sure that that has anything to do with your hardware... But back on topic ...I think you guys are on to something here... If I trigger a mouse down event, will it 'override' the existing one?

Comment: And as for the draggable implementation - I'm already planning to JQUI - the switching of focus is the real question.

Comment: Hmm - that does seem to perform the action I'm after - I think that spawning the DIV wherever the mouse is at that point ( rather than just another line in output ) might be the ticket. I'll give it a spin. Thanks.